# Oil's price vs price of oil

Tags: grammaticality

> Oil traders have profited handsomely from the recent rise in oil's price.

Is this grammatically right?

Comment: See for example https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15679/saxon-genitive-usage-question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we say a "hotel room" and not a "hotel's room"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room) //  "Oil's price" would only be used idiomatically to show a more particular association than the unmarked 'the price of oil': 'The major problem with using argan or or coconut  oil is the oil's price'.

Answer (score 1):

When we're talking about the price of some commodity, we almost always say *the price of X* rather than *X's price*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=price+of+oil%2Coil%27s+price%2Cprice+of+wheat%2Cwheat%27s+price%2C+price+of+roses%2C+rose%27s+price%2C+roses%27+price&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

We use possessives for *price* mainly in phrases like *member's price*, *manufacturer's price*, and so forth, which would mean the price a member pays for something or the price the manufacturer pays to produce something.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you shouldn't say "oil's price"; "oil" is not one of the inanimates with which you can use this construction (ship, earth, party, …).

[image]

However, the minority using this construction is so numerous (pehaps 200 hits in a Google research), that it becomes unrealistic to say that it is not acceptable: "[oil's price](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oil%27s%20price%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)".