# Can we say "the problem's"?

Tags: possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is using the possessive 's correct in “the car’s antenna”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/is-using-the-possessive-s-correct-in-the-cars-antenna)

Can we add apostrophe S, **'s**, to a word for an inanimate object as in the phrase

> the problem's underlying assumptions

to denote possession? Would it be natural and grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can.

I don't think a native speaker would have any problem with your sentence.

Comment: Fowler would have objected strongly. Indeed he did. This isn't the only thing I would in term object strongly too about Fowler, though.

Answer (score 2):

It can be a grammatically correct use of the possessive if the inanimate object actually possesses what follows.

I am not convinced that the *underlying assumptions* belong to the *problem*. They may have been used in constructing the problem or have been incorporated into the problem statement; but are they 'possessed' by the problem?

Comment: +1 the use of the genitive is fine grammar, but like you I am doubtful of the logic of the statement conveyed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is grammatically correct.

Though in spoken english, saying "The underlying assumptions of the problem" would be better, to avoid all ambiguity.