# Double possessive: a friend of Steven's

Tags: grammar, punctuation, possessives

I am wondering about the "double possessive" I have been reading about.

I have a couple of sentences as an example:

He’s a new client of Jane and Kevin’s and a close childhood friend of Steven O’Neill’s.

I thought that the above sentence was correct, because it sounds natural to use the apostrophe S to me, in the same way that we say "he's a friend of mine."

However, I have heard people criticize sentences such as that one above as having a "double possessive" because of the OF as well as the apostrophe S.

Is the above sentence correct or should it be:

He’s a new client of Jane and Kevin and a close childhood friend of Steven O’Neill.

Thank you - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Question Regarding Possessives with ('s) and (of)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103594/question-regarding-possessives-with-s-and-of).

Comment: @MoniqueH An apostrophe after O'Neill is not required. As you say, the possessive meaning is conveyed by the _of_ phrase. Your example means simply "He is a ... friend of Steven O'Neill".

Comment: Thank you Bill. I agree with you. It's just that the O'Neill's version sounds better to me for some reason!

Answer (score 2):

It's a shortened version of "A friend of Steven's *friends*".  That is, one of the set of people who are friends of Steven.