# Usage of " 's " in is Franco a friend of Jamie's?

Tags: differences, questions, possessives

What is the difference between "*is Franco a friend of Jamie's*?" and "*is Franco a friend of Jamie?*"?
Are both correct?
What is more appropriate?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I believe you will find the answer in *[Question Regarding Possessives with ('s) and (of)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103594/question-regarding-possessives-with-s-and-of)* or the cross-linked *[Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588)*

Comment: It might be that in the first case, Jamie knows who Franco is and considers him a friend. In the second case, it could be that Jamie has no idea who Franco is—but Franco still looks out for Jamie for one reason or another and, so, is a "friend of" him (or to him) without his knowledge. But that's only one interpretation. What exactly are you asking?