# Using "apostrophes" to show ownership of records in page?

Tags: writing, apostrophe

I had a debate with my co-worker about using apostrophes to show ownership of records which belongs to a page. He told me not to use an apostrophe.
This is the text in question :

> The Pagination in Lookup page isn’t displaying the next page’s record when
>   a user clicks next or page number. It will show the first page’s record.

Did I make a mistake ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I do not understand what you are trying to ask; are you saying you think the apostrophes in the example are correct or not correct? They look fine to me as written (there is [no rule against the Saxon genitive for inanimate objects](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031) and each *page* is presumably singular)— but to be honest, they are the least of your concerns here. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest.

Comment: I believe @choster is correct. If you were in fact asking about some other aspect of the apostrophe, please [edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/282167/edit) to make that clear. But in that quoted sentence, there is a lot that really is wrong, and I would suggest that ELU is not the right site for such text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not make a mistake. This is the correct usage of the possessive apostrophe.

However, I think the first sentence may be more clearly understood with this wording:

"The Pagination in 'Lookup Page' does not display the next page's record when user clicks 'Next' or a page number. Instead, it shows the first page's record."

At least, from what you've written, this is what I think you're trying to say. :)