# Is it correct to say peg location instead of peg's location?

Tags: possessives, compounds

So I was reading "Solitaire" rules and a few times it was written "peg location", isn't it correct to say "peg's location"? Also why do people say "game score" instead of "game's score"

Comment: It's a quirk of fate.

Comment: "if you are new to learning English, please consider whether your question might be better suited for English Language Learners."  (http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes, *peg location* is correct.

Comment: It's a good question OP, don't let the snarky, snobbish bums on this website get you down.  [This should help.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/is-using-the-possessive-s-correct-in-the-cars-antenna) regarding genitive of inanimate objects - also [check this](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/genitive_case.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Peg location means the location of the peg.  It is not possessive.  The location does not belong to the peg.

Comment: You can use either in this case. "Peg's location" would be meaningful. In this context, the two are interchangeable.

Comment: The *'s* construction, although often called the "possessive", is used for indicating many kinds of relationships, not just ownership. From a certain point of view, the location does "belong" to the peg: it is something associated with the peg. For example, we can say "I don't know Sandy's location" without implying that Sandy owns a location.