# Is it correct to have 's with these words?

Tags: possessives

Is the form: *vigings' history/legend* correct? Or the only way to show the possession in these cases is with the the **of** form?
More examples would be: *germans' ...*, *austrians' ...* etc.

Comment: No, this question is not a duplicate of [that question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1031/26083).   *That* question is entirely about whether it is correct to use a possessive form of *an inanimate object* (e.g., “the car’s antenna” or “the laptop’s display”), because objects can’t own things.   I’m not really sure what this question *is* about, but it’s clearly not the same, as it is talking about using a possessive for *a group **of people**.*

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean "the Vikings' history"?

It's perfectly grammatical, but a bit unusual. In a formal paper, you'd be more likely to find "the history of the Vikings", but in a magazine article, for example, you might find "the Vikings' history", as it has a less formal tone. But even in that context, "the history of the Vikings" and indeed "Viking history" are at least as likely.