# Is the "'s" here an abbreviation for be or is it the possessive form?

Tags: grammar

> The former was divided between admiration of the brilliancy which exercise had given to her complexion, and doubt as to the occasion's justifying her coming so far alone.
>
> – Pride and Prejudice

Comment: The sentence would not make any sense if it stood for **is**. It's genitive.

Answer (score 2):

It is genitive. The gerund ***justifying*** is modified by the possessive ***the occasion's***. *[Gerunds preceded by possessives](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=90SDm90b7Xlw.html#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20possessive%20before%20a%20gerund&text=This%20noun%20or%20pronoun%20is,celebrated%20Gord%27s%20winning%20the%20contest.)* is a known construction, but this sentence is quite particular: the PP

> [as to the occasion's justifying [her coming so far alone]].

contains the possessive *the occasion's* - subject of the gerund *justifying*, and then the object of the gerund is ***her coming so far alone*** - an accusative pronoun followed by a participle. The sentence is indeed intricate, but in an elegant and stylish way characteristic to conversations of Jane Austen's time.

As for the *possessive 's with inanimate things*, [this ELU post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/is-using-the-possessive-s-correct-in-the-cars-antenna) explains it very well.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Comment: That is, "the occasion's justifying" and "her coming" are both the same grammatical structure - gerunds preceded by possessives.