# Is using possessive apostrophe -s instead of "of form" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I learned that the possessive apostrophe -s is used for living beings and the "of" form for non living things:

- The dog's name is Sherlock
- The color of the flower is yellow

However, I have noticed that these rules are often ignored in spoken language:

- The road's name is Privet Drive
- The name of the dog is Sherlock

Are these mistakes made by non-native speakers or are these just theoretical grammatical rules that are not really strictly applied by native speakers in their spoken language as well?

Does one stand out directly as a non-native speaker with these errors?

Comment: Duplicate of several questions including [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/why-are-some-possessives-formed-with-of-but-not-apostrophe-s) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/is-using-the-possessive-apostrophe-correct-in-the-cars-antenna). There are also questions about whether a dog/cat/baby counts as an animate being if you search for them.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever told you that *the possessive apostrophe -s is used for living beings and the "of" form for non living things* is [obviously talking nonsense...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20earth%27s%20crust%2Cthe%20crust%20of%20the%20earth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

I rest my case.

Comment: The duplicates have already been pointed out.

Comment: There's probably much more that *could* be said about this issue than even the very long answers in the question you linked to. I don't care if no-one upvotes my picture, but I think the OP's initial assertion here is so ridiculous it needs to be clearly and unambiguously refuted by a very common counterexample. I'd rather see questions at this level migrated to ELL anyway.